# Primary Key and Foreign Key on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know this questions already are asked but I am stuck...
I have 2 tables (clubs and membres):

In my table **clubs** I have 3 fields id_club, name_club, type_sport_club

Everything is working on my table Clubs

However I am stuck in my table **Membres**, I don't understand...

My problem is I only get number of my fk and no the name of club...
[image]

For information I have 3 fields id_membre, name_membre, fk_club

So...In my database I have this

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('membres', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_membre');
            $table->string('name_membre');
            $table->integer('fk_club')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('fk_club')->references('id_client')->on('clients');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Then on Model I have this

```
class Membre extends Model
{
    //
    protected  $fillable = ['name_membre', 'fk_club'];
}
```

After for Controller I have this

```
public function index()
     {
         $membres = Membre::oldest()->paginate(5);
         return view('admin.membres.index', compact('membres'))
                   ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)-1)*5);
     }
```

In my index.blade I have this

```
@foreach($membres as $membre)
                <tr>
                   <td> {{$membre->name_membre}}</td>
                   <td> {{$membre->fk_club}}</td>
                   <td>
                     <form method="POST" action="{{ route('membres.destroy', $membre) }} ">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{route('membres.edit',$membre->id_membre)}}">Editer</a>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Deleter</button>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is how SQL relationships fundamentally work. The foreign key provides a specification on which table you need to *join* and on which field in order to get all data related to a given row. If you had the club name on every member of that club there would be too much duplication and other wonderful things such as update and delete anomalies. @Alex suggested using eloquent relationships and I think that's definitely something you need to look into but first you might need to also look into relational database basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `Membre` Model Add this

```
class Membre extends Model{
  //
  protected  $fillable = ['name_membre', 'fk_club'];

  public function club(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Club', 'fk_club');
  }
```

}

You can get this data on your view file by

```
<td> {{$membre->club->name_club}}</td>
```

And your Club Model add this

```
class Club extends Model{
  public function membre(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Membre', 'fk_club','id_club');
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your foreign key in the members migration references `id_client` in the `clients` table, you probably want that to reference `id_club` in the `clubs` table (unless your table is actually called clients).

Then to get the name of the club a member belongs to, you'll have to add a function called `club` to your `Membre` model, which returns something like `$this->belongsTo('App\Club');`. If you haven't done so, you should also add a `members` function to your `Club` model, which returns something like `$this->hasMany('App\Membre');`.

In your view you can access the name of the club with `$membre->club->name_club`.

[Here's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) a link to the Laravel documentation about Eloquent relationships, maybe that helps clearing things up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your relation,

```
class Membre extends Model
{
    //
    protected  $fillable = ['name_membre', 'fk_club'];

    public function club()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Club', 'fk_club');
    }
}
```

Now you can use this like below,

```
<td> {{$membre->club->name_club}}</td>
```